# Type org.json.JSONException is defined multiple times

Tags: android, gradle

when I am generating signed APK in android this error is coming again and again,and jetified-jav-json file is opening.this is may be due to my gradle file --This is  error generated by android studio --

Type org.json.CDL is defined multiple times: C:\Users\91971.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\4ff16b76dc52b01ac4898d797a9f3375\jetified-java-json.jar:org/json/CDL.class, C:\Users\91971\AndroidStudioProjects\APS-Money-updated\aeps_lib-1July\build.transforms\832bfa6b3f0d8c75ed631f792cb4e02d\jetified-aeps_lib-1July-runtime.jar:org/json/CDL.class

this is my build.gradle--

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
  android {
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'AndroidManifest.xml'
}

compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.aps.apsmoney"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionName "1.0"
    versionCode 1
    //versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    android {
        lintOptions {
            checkReleaseBuilds false
            abortOnError false
        }
    }
    aaptOptions { cruncherEnabled = false }

}
buildTypes {
    release {

        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
       // proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        zipAlignEnabled true
        debuggable = false
        jniDebuggable = false
    }
}
```

}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

```
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation files('libs/signpost-core-1.2.1.2.jar')
implementation('de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.5@aar') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
}
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation files('libs/java-json.jar')
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation project(':aeps_lib-1July')
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.3.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This is due to some unused dependency i had added...remove unsused dependency and problem get resolved....kindly remove dependency one by one check which dependency is effecting project....It tooked about 1 week for me to find thid bug...